# Web Deploy 3.0 very slow on large website .net MVC Website

Tags: asp.net, iis, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I am using Web Deploy over the web for a large website and it is redeploying all of the images files every on every single deployment which takes quite a while.

I am considering copying the entire web deployment package over first to the server to deploy rather than deploying via a build server.

Is there a setting for Web Deploy so that it the package does not overwrite the images files upon every deploy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDeploy only deploys files that it has deemed as having changed. By default, this involves comparing the files' Last Modified timestamps. If your source control / build process causes these to be updated, but they will always be updated.

There is an alternative. If you pass [`-useCheckSum`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to the command line, it will compare the *contents* of the files (via a checksum).

It would be my preference to fix the issue that's causing your last modified dates to change, though, as `-useCheckSum` is obviously going to be slower.